# make the reference object refer an other object whithout change the origin object

Tags: javascript, oop

I have an object `a`:

```
var a = {//some properties....};
```

Then `b` refer `a`:

```
var b = a;
function modifyB()
{
//do something with b to change a
}
//after finish I want from b to refer an other object c
b = c;
```

The problem that a refer c , how can I change b without changing a after `modifyB()`.

Comment: You need to make a copy of the object.

Comment: If it's a simple object (ie no methods) you can do `var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));` to do a quick clone.

Comment: can't use `JSON.parse` , because `a` contain methods.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object